# Button State Persistence

Tags: meteor

I have a 'Create Post' button in which a user can use to submit a post. I only want the user to be able to create one post at a time. So the user would have to remove the first post to create another, or they would have to wait for that post to be removed by someone else - which is perfectly acceptable.

Also, I want the button to be `disabled` when there is already a live post of theirs.

So, basically, what's the best way to attach the state of the button to the state of the post, so that as soon as the post is removed, the button is then enabled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, spacebars makes this really easy to do. Have a look at the "Smarter Attributes" section of [this post](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/spacebars-secrets-exploring-meteor-new-templating-engine/).

Here is an example:

```html
<template name="post">
  <button disabled={{isDisabled}}>Create Post</button>
</template>
```

```js
Template.post.isDisabled = function () {
  return Posts.findOne();
};
```

In this case the button will be disabled if any posts were found, but you can easily modify that to your specific requirements.